# Cx_Freeze not working

Tags: python, cx-freeze

Code Used:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable

setup(name='Submission', version='1.0', description='seperate row values',executables=[Executable("Submission.py")])
```

after I build the setup.py , it creates a folder and the exe file as well. But, the exe file does not do anything when double clicked .

Submission.py unzip's a folder traverses through csv file and generates new operated csv with same file name in seperate folder.
Submission.py works fine but submission.exe doesnt give any output

Only module which generates exe is cx_Freeze but this exe is not able to give desired output

submission.py code is:

```
import patoolib
import glob
import os
import csv

zipSrc="C:\\Users\\Suraj\\Documents\\Pyhton\\Python scripts\\Input.zip"
zipDst="C:\\Users\\Suraj\\Documents\\Pyhton\\Python scripts\\Zip Output"
formatSrc="C:\\Users\\Suraj\\Documents\\Pyhton\\Python scripts\\Output Format.csv"
finalOutput="C:\\Users\\Suraj\\Documents\\Pyhton\\Python scripts\\Output"

colValues=[]
widthValues=[]
sepValues=[]
widthSum=0


with open(formatSrc,'r') as forMat:
    forMatReader = csv.reader(forMat)
    for line in forMatReader:
        colValues.append(line[1])
        widthValues.append(line[0])


for i in widthValues:
    widthSum += int(i)
    sepValues.append(widthSum)

patoolib.extract_archive(zipSrc,outdir=zipDst)
os.chdir(zipDst)
fileList=glob.glob("*.csv")

for file in fileList:
    with open(file,'r') as f, open(finalOutput+"\\"+file,'w',newline='') as f2:
        fileReader = f.readlines()
        writeData = csv.writer(f2)

        writeData.writerow(colValues)

        for line in fileReader:
            start=0
            temp=[]
            for value in sepValues:
                temp.append(line[start:value])
                start = value
            writeData.writerow(temp)
```

I tried with pyinstaller as well but again , no output .

Thnx for the help in advance!!!

Comment: What platform are you using? Which version of cx_Freeze? Is there any output on the command line? Can you provide the script Submission.py or something that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Im using windows 64 bit. cx_Freeze version is 5.0.1. If i run my code via command line, yes I get the desired output. But I want to run it as an exe file. I have added the submission.py script in my question.